# Any way to do overlayBegin event for Google Map API3 Drawing Library?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drawing

Is it possible some how to catche the button click on the Google Map API3 Drawing Library Toolbar? 
I need to do some manipulation before the overlay will created (for example add limits of overlay on the map - riche the limit overlays), but we have only overlayComplete events for this tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to enable the drawing library, but hide the drawing control. Then you can build your own control and handle any events you want. It's kind of a pain, but not that hard, as the API has all the calls you need to start drawing each of the different geometry types.